# Rails - Apartment - MySQL drop tenant database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, apartment-gem

I am creating a multi tenant application in rails using apartment gem and MySQL as database. I have setup apartment following https://gorails.com/episodes/multitenancy-with-apartment .

After this whenever I created a new subdomain, new database was created for each subdomain. Now if I execute rake db:drop, it drops only the main db and all the subdomain databases remain intact.

My query is how to drop the subdomain databases.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to list the existing tenants using:

```
Apartment.tenant_names
```

And you should be able to delete one using

```
Apartment::Tenant.drop('tenant_name')
```

https://github.com/influitive/apartment#dropping-tenants

However,  I'm using Apartment with PostreSQL,  the generated schemas werent being really deleted properly, i had to do it manually using

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS #{tenant} CASCADE;"
```